# Can you add to the Google Chrome > Developer Tools > Emulation > Device list?

Tags: google-chrome, blackberry, emulation, google-chrome-devtools

All,
Pretty straight forward question here....
Can we add to the list of preset devices in Google Chrome>Developer Tools>Emulation>Device list?
I am running "Version 34.0.1847.116 m"

I am looking to test a web app that would run on BlackBerry OS 7 and earlier devices.

I cannot find any details on whether this list can be added too and what devices are possibly available.

Thanks for any insights...

Comment: I would like that too, since there are no 240x320 devices in the presets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Unfortunately, Google Chrome does not offer developers the option to add their own device. However, you do have the option of changing the dimensions and user agent, so you can use those settings to emulate the desired device.</s>

Curiosity got the best of me, so I did try to change some files in Chrome's core installation files where I thought  I could add an entry myself, but this just borked my Chrome making all web pages and extensions inaccessible. I wouldn't recommend you to try anything similar either.

Edit: The newer versions of Google Chrome (including stable) have added the support for adding Custom devices. [Frederik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250910/can-you-add-to-the-google-chrome-developer-tools-emulation-device-list/29118351#29118351) describes the steps on how to do it but a more reliable source would be to check [Google Chrome's documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode#custom-devices) on this since the way to do this tends to keep changing after a few versions.

Comment: If I just cut and past the BB user agent in that field and change dimensions to the device, do you think that would work?

Comment: Yes, the page will then load according to that dimension and user agent. However, the rendering might not be exact since Chrome and BB use different browser engines.

Comment: the tools are so inaccurate and unreliable

Answer (score 4):

I found the need to expand this list from needing to test my site with the [Googlebot smartphone User-Agent](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/references/googlebot), which is not in the regular list of devices (although it surely would be nice, since [this is how Google determines your mobile-friendly-ness](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/)  and consequently your mobile index rank)

As such, this list can't be altered. But: there is a way.

1. Get [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html), which is the (possibly unstable)
   dev/bleeding-edge version of Chrome.
2. In this version of Chrome, when pressing `F12` and selecting the gears icon (`Settings`), you now have a tab on the left side called `Devices`".
3. Here you will find the most missed `Add custom device...` button. In here, you can add your own user agent with your own User-Agent string.

I found this out by reading [this](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode#custom-devices), it's a thorough walkthrough of the options for advanced mobile emulation in Chrome.

Comment: No need to get canary anymore. Thanks for this though. This should now be the accepted answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

There is a way of course! Open up the mobile device window and you will see in the right hand corner a 3 dot icon[settings] and a bottom window will open up in the Dev Tools window. You can then change the viewport size and Save As... pick whatever the name your device is!